# How to customize FOS UserBundle URLs

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've installed [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and I'd like to customize the urls to be `/account/login`, `/account/register`, `/account/logout` instead of `/login`, `/register`, `/logout`

I know I can modify the routing config of the bundle, but it doesn't seem to be the proper way.

Comment: or copy the whole routing xml's from the fosUserBundle to your app folder and customize them there or change the prefix they suggest in step6 of the [install docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files)

Comment: No job for `.htaccess` - completely wrong direction !! you can either copy the routes over and include only the changed ones or just override single ones as described in my answer.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### How to override / change FOSUserBundle's routes

You can override i.e the `/register` route in your `app/config/routing.yml` by **re-declaring** it **after** importing FOSUserBundle's XML routes as resources.

```
fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

# ...

fos_user_registration_register:
    path:      /account/register
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:register }
```

... or just change the prefix when importing:

```
fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /account/register

# no need to override the route
```

The same goes for `/login` and `/logout` :

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

# ...

fos_user_security_login:
    path:      /account/login
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login, _method: POST }

fos_user_security_logout:
    path:      /account/login
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout, _method: POST }
```

### Another way to override login and logout url's

login and logout paths can aswell be configured directly in your `app/config/security.yml`:

```
security:
    firewalls: 
        your_firewall:
            # ...
            form_login:
                login_path: /account/login  # instead of fos_user_security_login
                # ...
            logout:
                path: /account/logout       # instead of fos_user_security_logout
                # ...
```

### List of all of FOSUserBundle's routes in YAML format

You can directly change and then include these in your `app/config/routing.yml` ( no need to import the ones the bundle provides as resources then) ... or put them all into a single file and include that one as a resource...

```
# -> from @FOSUserBundle/Resources/routing/change_password.xml

fos_user_change_password:
    pattern: /profile/password/change
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST

# -> from @FOSUserBundle/Resources/routing/group.xml

fos_user_group_list:
    pattern: /groups/list
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Group:list }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

fos_user_group_new:
    pattern: /groups/new
    pattern:
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Group:new }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

fos_user_group_show:
    pattern: /groups/{groupname}
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Group:show }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

fos_user_group_edit:
    pattern: /groups/{groupname}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Group:edit }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST

fos_user_group_delete:
    pattern: /groups/{groupname}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Group:delete }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

# -> from @FOSUserBundle/Resources/routing/profile.xml

fos_user_profile_show:
    pattern: /profile/show
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:show }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

fos_user_profile_edit:
    pattern: /profile/edit
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST

# -> from @FOSUserBundle/Resources/routing/registration.xml

fos_user_registration_register:
    pattern: /registration
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:register }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST

fos_user_registration_check_email:
    pattern: /registration/check-email
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:checkEmail }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

fos_user_registration_confirm:
    pattern: /registration/confirm/{token}
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirm }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

fos_user_registration_confirmed:
    pattern: /registration/confirmed
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirmed }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

# -> from @FOSUserBundle/Resources/routing/resetting.xml

fos_user_resetting_request:
    pattern: /profile/password/reset
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Resetting:request }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

fos_user_resetting_send_email:
    pattern: /profile/password/reset
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Resetting:sendEmail }
    requirements:
        _method: POST

fos_user_resetting_check_email:
    pattern: /profile/password/reset/check-email
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:checkEmail }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

fos_user_resetting_reset:
    pattern: /profile/password/reset/{token}
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:reset }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST

# -> from @FOSUserBundle/Resources/routing/security.xml

fos_user_security_login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST

fos_user_security_check:
    pattern: /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

fos_user_security_logout:
    pattern: /logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST
```

Comment: you need to setup login path and logout path app/config/security.yml for correct redirection. that step is mandatory I think

Comment: The `pattern`  and `_method` are deprecated since version 2.2.

Comment: nifir,you have errors in your path. In the "Resetting" group, you use `FOSUserBundle:Registration`, and this will give an error on all paths.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I've corrected a couple of minor mistakes and added an Symfony 3 version (leaving the Symfony 2 version there). It's just waiting to be peer reviewed.