# Overriding FOSUserBUndle Controllers Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to override *FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController* to add some functionalities (to manage the fields I add in my registration form etc).

I do not know why, after overriding it, symphony ignores my controller. This is not the first time, I also tried to override others ... never found solutions ...

```
<?php
namespace FP\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;


    class RegistrationController extends BaseController
    {
        public function registerAction()
        {
            $response = parent::registerAction();

            echo "FPUserBundle";
            // do custom stuff

            return $response;
        }
    }
```

.

```
<?php

namespace FP\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class FPUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

.

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

/**
 * Controller managing the registration
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        echo "FOSUserBundle";
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);//active l'user

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            //--- ajout des données pour les champs ajoutés ---
                $user->setDateInscrip(new \DateTime());
                $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_USER'));
            //--------- Fin de l'ajout ---------
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user to check his email provider
     */
    public function checkEmailAction()
    {
        $email = $this->get('session')->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $this->get('session')->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with email "%s" does not exist', $email));
        }

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:checkEmail.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user
     */
    public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
    {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
        }

        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user his account is now confirmed
     */
    public function confirmedAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fp_user_inscrip', array('user' => $user)));
        /*
        return $this->render('FPPlatformBundle:Index:index.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));*/
    }
}
```

Despite these codes, when I run the check, "FPUserBundle" is not displayed, while "FOSUserBundle" appears well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding Classes (Controllers are classes too!) will give the new class all the futures that the base-class has (except direct access to private methods or properties). But do not forget that the base-class still can be used beside the new class. It dependence's which class you instantiate.

```
$a = new BaseClass();
```

vs

```
$a = new NewClass();
```

So the question is which one will Symfony use? And THAT is what you can manage with the routing. as long this is in your app/config/routing.yml:

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Symfony will use the original FOSUserBundle controllers. Just find those xml files in the vendor/FOS.. directory and copy them to your own project. Change above showed rule to your own bundle and change the controllernames in the xml files. Of course you could write your own .yml files too.

[**read more**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444390/override-fosuserbundle-routes-symfony2)

Answer (score 2):

Check that you've added the new Bundle into app/AppKernel.php::registerBundles function.