# Symfony2 Redirect user after succesfull register with FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have tried a lot of method to resolv this problem, but it's still not working. What i want, is than after the user success to register he is redirecting to the wanted page.

So, i have a UserBundle with :

- in UserBundle/EventListener

  ```
  namespace MDB\UserBundle\EventListener;

  use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
  use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

  class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  private $router;

  public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {

      $this->router = $router;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
      return array(
          FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
      );
  }

  public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event) {
      $url = $this->router->generate('mdb_platform_homepage');

      $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
  }

  }

  ?>
  ```
- in services.yml (of user bunde)

  services:

  ```
          mdb_user.registration.form.type:
              class: MDB\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
              tags:
                  - { name: form.type, alias: mdb_user_registration }

          mdb.user.validator.contains_user:
              class: MDB\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsUserValidator
              arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]       
              tags:
                  - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: contains_user } 

          mdb_user.registration_complet:
              class: MDB\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
              arguments: ["@router"]
              tags:
                  - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
  ```

i have tried a lot of other config and check the other forums but it seems the redirection never work.

Anyone have an idea?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem like that :

in app/config/routing :

add this

```
fos_user_registration_confirmed:
    pattern: /registration/confirmed
    defaults: { _controller: MDBUserBundle:User:confirmed }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

and in the targeted controller do what you want :

```
  public function confirmedAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MDBPlatformBundle:Default:index.html.twig'
        );
    }
```

a good link who can help for similar situation : [How to customize FOS UserBundle URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608458/how-to-customize-fos-userbundle-urls)

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that :

**Changing the default Page**

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                use_referer: true
                default_target_path: default_security_target
```

**Control the Redirect URL from inside the Form**

```
{# src/Acme/SecurityBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig #}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="account" />

    <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
```

and in your security :

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                target_path_parameter: redirect_url
```

Read more at : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html

Comment: Thx for your answer but  i know this way ,i already did it and it work for the form_login, but i dont know how to do for the register_form.

Maybe there is somthing like that :

'form_register:
      success_path : xxxx;
'
?

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify LeZelkins accepted answer even more if you just want to redirect. Use the FrameworkBundle RedirectController:

```
# routing.yml
fos_user_registration_confirmed:
    path: /registration/confirmed
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /admin/dashboard
```

Comment: What "doesnt work"? This is copy/paste from a working project of mine. 
a) You override fosuserbundle routes by redeclaring them. 
b) Even the symfony documentation gives a similar example of "How to Configure a Redirect without a custom Controller" (http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_in_config.html)