# How does redirection is performed by FOSUserBundle for /register route?

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, fosuserbundle, http-status-code-301

After installing and configuring successfully FOSUserBundle for Symfony 2.3.4, I observed that the two routes (`path/register` and `path/register/`) both work. In my routing configuration, I only have the route `path/register/`.

I don't have any .htaccess  file associated with my project (which runs under Apache server).

When I inspect under developement tools, I see that `path/register` gives a 301 Moved Permanently status code and redirects to `path/register/` with 200 status code. What is the mechanism/code that allowed this?

Any explanations are highly appreciated.

**Edit based on first answer:**

I am not trying to understand how routing works, or how to customize my routing. I am trying to understand the mechanism behind redirection (from `/register` to `/register/`); Is it implemented somewhere in the core Symfony2 or is it a browser related?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fos user bundle routing is explained in detail here:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/routing.md

Here you find a answer 
[How to customize FOS UserBundle URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608458/how-to-customize-fos-userbundle-urls)

Generally:

Routing is handled in different ways in Symfony (config files, annotations,...)

Check your routing.yml as a first entry point. Get all available routes by using the console tool:
php app/console route:debug

Annotations usage:
* @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")