# FosUserBundle: How to override the default /profile path to custom path?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, fosuserbundle

When u visit the /profile path it takes you to a default profile page.

I made changes so when you visit a profile you need to add an id to the url to visit the correct page.

However, the /profile still goes to the default page, how can I disable this route or make it go to a custom path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml`, you will see the following routings. You can overwrite any routing (or other configuration) by using the same name in your own routing

```
<route id="fos_user_profile_show" path="/" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Profile:show</default>
</route>

<route id="fos_user_profile_edit" path="/edit" methods="GET POST">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit</default>
</route>
```

In your own routing.yml you'd simply overwrite like this:

```
fos_user_profile_show:
    path: /profile/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Profile:show }

fos_user_profile_edit:
    path: /profile/edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Profile:edit }
```

Note that most likely you are no longer using the default `ProfileController`, but instead have your own `ProfileController` extending the FOSUserBundle `ProfileController`. That's why I also changed the controller to `AppBundle:Profile:edit`, but obviously this needs to match your code.

Also note the `{id}` needs to be implemented in your code, ex.:

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $id)
```

Also see here for a more detailed answer (for another route): [How to customize FOS UserBundle URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608458/how-to-customize-fos-userbundle-urls)